# File Access Denied Using VSBuild@1 Task

Tags: azure-devops

Running Azure pipeline and getting the error below:

```
##[error]Access to the path 'C:\azagent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.166.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\MSBuildHelpers.psm1' is denied.
```

I tried using MSBuild as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with the following things in the pipeline to resolve the issue:

- Ensure the agent you are using has been upgraded to the latest version **`3.x`**.
- Enable **`AGENT_FORCE_CREATE_TASKS_DIRECTORY`** knob as a pipeline variable.

  ```yaml
  variables:
    AGENT_FORCE_CREATE_TASKS_DIRECTORY: true
  ```